# How to retrieve the first node of a XML after use simplexml_load_string in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the follow xml where the first node is the `<Cancellation>`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<Cancellation>
    <version>message-version</version>
    <customerID>customer-identifier</customerID>
    <invoiceID>invoice-number</invoiceID>
    <cancellationDate>yyyy-mm-dd</cancellationDate>
    <reason>reason</reason>
    <reasonCode>reason-code</reasonCode>
    <attempts>attempts-count</attempts>
    <merchantID>rocketgate merchant-identifier</merchantID>
    <merchantSiteID>site-id</merchantSiteID>
    <udf01>user-data</udf01>
</Cancellation>
```

Eventually I could have a similar xml but for a complete different process like registration, like the follow:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
    <Registration>
        <version>message-version</version>
        <customerID>customer-identifier</customerID>
        <invoiceID>invoice-number</invoiceID>
        <merchantID>rocketgate merchant-identifier</merchantID>
        <merchantSiteID>site-id</merchantSiteID>
        <udf01>user-data</udf01>
    </Registration>
```

I will need to catch this first node in a if condition to redirect to the appropriate path.

Following this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) I got an array from the sent xml:

```
$xmlString = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xmlObj    = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$xmlJSON = json_encode($xmlObj);
$xmlArray = json_decode($xmlJSON, true);
```

But the issue is that I can't see the first `<Cancellation>` or `<Registration>` node after passing the xml string to an object.
[image]

Even the examples in the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) is not showing the first node.

I need to test if it is a Cancellation or a Registration. How could I do that?

Comment: A plea if it's not already too late: don't convert your XML to an array (using the json_encode/decode hack); keep it as a `SimpleXMLElement` so you can use the features of SimpleXML like the `->getName()` function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the tag name of the root element in XML just use `getName()` on the SimpleXMLElement...

```
echo $xmlObj->getName();
```